# Why does JMX show XNIO ConnectionCount -1?

Tags: undertow, xnio

So I am trying to get JMX metrics on my Undertow webserver's number of open connections.

I used JMXTerm and selected the following bean because it is bound to port 8080, which is what my application is running on:

```
org.xnio:address="/0.0.0.0:8080",provider="nio",type=Xnio,worker="XNIO-2"
```

I can see a metric for ConnectionCount however when I query for it I get -1

```
$>get ConnectionCount
#mbean = org.xnio:address="/0.0.0.0:8080",provider="nio",type=Xnio,worker="XNIO-2":
ConnectionCount = -1;
```

I would expect the value to be some positive number, not sure what -1 is even supposed to represent?

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be a bug. Refer : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-8082 & https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-8083